# hive throwing error when I give alias name to my sub query

Tags: hive

I am very new to Hive, so have a very basic question. In a Hive, can a sub query be given an alias and used outside in main query?

Basically when I try:

```sql
(SELECT *,
        row_number() over(PARTITION BY ID, source_name
                          ORDER BY TIME DESC) rn
 FROM x_table) temp_name
```

I get the following error:

> AnalysisException: syntax error in line 1: undefined: .....)) temp_name^ Encountered: Identifier expected limit,order,union caused by : Exception :Syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
Select 
    * 
from 
    (select 
        *
        ,row_number() over(partition by ID,source_name order by time desc) rn 
    from x_table
    ) t;
```